# probability density function of a cumulative density function

Tags: probability, density-function, integral

I was reading that the probability density function (pdf say $f(x)$) of a cumulative distribution function (cdf say denoted as $F(x)$) is uniformly distributed from 0 to 1.

Basically this is what I read:

---

Suppose that $Z$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,1)$, and that we transform the values of $z$ using some function $f(\cdot )$ so that $y = f(z)$. The distribution of $y$ will be governed by

$$p(y) = p(z) \left|\frac{dz}{dy}\right|$$

where, in this case, $p(z) = 1$. Our goal is to choose the function $f(z)$ such that the resulting values of $y$ have some specific desired distribution $p(y)$. Integrating the above, we obtain

$$z = h(y) := \int\limits_{-\infty}^{y} p(\hat{y}) d \hat{y}$$

which is the indefinite integral of $p(y)$. Thus, $y = h^{-1} (z)$ , and so we have to transform the uniformly distributed random variable using a function which is the inverse of the indefinite integral of the desired distribution.

---

My question is:

I am not sure how to get $z$ equal to the integral. Because it says "integrating the above, we obtain $z = h(y)$" .

But I am not sure how to get $z$ equal that because if I integrate the right hand-side of that formula from negative infinity to an arbitrary y-value, it means I sum up all the probability value of y from negative infinity up to that particular $y$-value right? 
But could someone show or point out how $z$ will equal that integral?

Thank you

Comment: That's not a pdf of a cdf, it's the pdf of a transformed random variable, where the transformation is the variable's cdf. E.g. if $X\sim F_X(x)$ (for some continuous variate $X$, and you apply the transform $Y=F_X(X)$, then $Y$ is uniform.

Comment: Oh Thank you Glen_b, but could you explain why performing the integration from negative infinity to an arbitrary y value on the right-hand side of the first formula will arrive at the variable z?

Comment: Your $z$ is the CDF of the random variable from -$\infty$ to $y$.  The integral of the PDF from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is unity (one).

Comment: Hi wrtsvkrfm, I understand z is cdf of the variable y. But I don't understand why integrating the right hand-side of the first formula would lead to z.

Comment: basically I don't understand why integrating the right hand-side of the first formula from negative infinity to say an arbitrary y value would lead to the value "z" . Basically the mathematical step I guess that I am missing.

Comment: could someone kindly explain why? or answer my question as to why integrating the right hand side of first formula will lead to z ?